# How to find eigenvalue of a matrix using LAPACK in C?

Tags: c

Would you please upload a video on how to install the LAPACK library on Ubuntu and how to use it in C?

Actually I want to diagonalize a matrix and find out the eigenvalue, so someone suggest me to use LAPACK; but, I do'nt know how to use it .

Answer (score 2):

1. Install it using (see [difference between lapacke and lapack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875415/difference-between-lapacke-and-lapack)):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install liblapacke-dev
   ```
2. Lookup lapack function name: [routines](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/individualroutines.html)

   Function used to get eigen-value `LAPACKE_dgeev`
3. Write your code:

   Modify this example from [lapacke](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html) to fit your needs

   ```c
   /* Calling DGELS using row-major order */

   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <lapacke.h>

   int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
   {
      double a[5][3] = {1,1,1,2,3,4,3,5,2,4,2,5,5,4,3};
      double b[5][2] = {-10,-3,12,14,14,12,16,16,18,16};
      lapack_int info,m,n,lda,ldb,nrhs;
      int i,j;

      m = 5;
      n = 3;
      nrhs = 2;
      lda = 3;
      ldb = 2;

      info = LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'N',m,n,nrhs,*a,lda,*b,ldb);

      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
         for(j=0;j<nrhs;j++)
         {
            printf("%lf ",b[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
      }
      return(info);
   }
   ```
4. Compile:

   ```
   cc main.c -llapacke
   ```